# Simulation of 2D elastic balls

Tags: python, performance, beginner, numpy, physics

Following this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35211114/5805330) and this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision), I wrote a Python script to simulate physics of 2D elastic balls.

I define the physical behaviour of each ball in the `Ball` class. Then the function `solve_step` enables to compute position and velocity of every ball for one time step.

The balls are moving inside a square. Two balls rebound elastically from each other (see `compute_coll` function). When a ball hits one edge of the square, it bounces off elastically (see `compute_refl` function).

Note that I'm using 2 functions `step1` and `step2` for `solve_step` because that makes the program faster.

Moreover I provide a main to run an example of simulation.

Here I don't show the code used to display the simulation in a window because I think this is another issue.

Any ideas on optimizing and simplifying this code?

```
import numpy as np
```

**Ball class**

```
class Ball:
    """Define physics of elastic collision."""

    def __init__(self, mass, radius, position, velocity):
        """Initialize a Ball object

        mass the mass of ball
        radius the radius of ball
        position the position vector of ball
        velocity the velocity vector of ball
        """
        self._mass = mass
        self._radius = radius
        self._position = position
        self._velocity = velocity
        self._vafter = np.copy(velocity) # temp storage for velocity of next step

    def compute_step(self, step):
        """Compute position of next step."""
        self._position += step * self._velocity

    def new_velocity(self):
        """Store velocity of next step."""
        self._velocity = self._vafter

    def compute_coll(self, ball, step):
        """Compute velocity after elastic collision with another ball."""
        m1 = self._mass
        m2 = ball._mass
        r1 = self._radius
        r2 = ball._radius
        v1 = self._velocity
        v2 = ball._velocity
        x1 = self._position
        x2 = ball._position
        di = x2-x1
        norm = np.linalg.norm(di)
        if norm-r1-r2 < step*abs(np.dot(v1-v2,di))/norm:
            self._vafter = v1 - 2.*m2/(m1+m2) * np.dot(v1-v2,di)/(np.linalg.norm(di)**2.) * di

    def compute_refl(self, step, size):
        """Compute velocity after hitting an edge.

        step the step of computation
        size the size of a square edge
        """
        r = self._radius
        v = self._velocity
        x = self._position
        projx = step*abs(np.dot(v,np.array([1.,0.])))
        projy = step*abs(np.dot(v,np.array([0.,1.])))
        if abs(x[0])-r < projx or abs(size-x[0])-r < projx:
            self._vafter[0] *= -1
        if abs(x[1])-r < projy or abs(size-x[1])-r < projy:
            self._vafter[1] *= -1.
```

**Solver**

```
def step1(ball_list, step, size):
    """Detect reflection and collision of every ball."""
    index_list = range(len(ball_list))
    for i in index_list:
        ball_list[i].compute_refl(step,size)
        for j in index_list:
            if i!=j:
                ball_list[i].compute_coll(ball_list[j],step)
    return ball_list

def step2(ball_list, step):
    """Compute position of every ball."""
    index_list = range(len(ball_list)) 
    for i in index_list:
        ball_list[i].new_velocity()
        ball_list[i].compute_step(step)
    return ball_list

def solve_step(ball_list, step, size):
    """Solve a step for every ball."""
    ball_list = step1(ball_list, step, size)
    ball_list = step2(ball_list, step)
    return ball_list
```

**Main**

```
def init_list(N):
    """Generate N Ball objects in a list."""
    ball_list = []
    r = 10.
    for i in range(N):
        v = 10.*np.array([(-1.)**i,1.])
        pos = 400./float(N+1)*np.array([float(i+1),float(i+1)])
        ball_list.append(Ball(r, r, pos, v))
    return ball_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ball_list = init_list(10)
    size = 400.
    step = 0.05
    for i in range(5000):
        solve_step(ball_list, step, size)
```

Comment: I created a specific post about the code used to display the simulation in a window. [This is here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/132413/95659).

Comment: Is this python 2.7 or 3?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 but it should work with python 3 if you try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general for optimising code you should look at a profiler to tell you
where the specific hotspots are.

There are also some differences between Python 2.7 and Python 3, but
without some confirmation I'll just note that with Python 3 you have a
higher number of builtins that generate things on demand rather than
building up e.g. whole lists etc. then discarding them immediately.
That applies to e.g. the `range` function.

- In `step2` the `range(len(ball_list))` is unnecessary.  You already
  have a list, so just iterate over that instead:

  ```
  def step2(ball_list, step):
      """Compute position of every ball."""
      for ball in ball_list:
          ball.new_velocity()
          ball.compute_step(step)
  ```

  Since this is purely destructive there's no need to return the list
  either.  It also reads much nicer.
- For `step1` again you don't need to return the list.  Also, same idea,
  don't generate a new list with indexes, just do it on the fly:

  ```
  def step1(ball_list, step, size):
      """Detect reflection and collision of every ball."""
      for ball1 in ball_list:
          ball1.compute_refl(step, size)
          for ball2 in ball_list:
              if ball1 is not ball2:
                  ball1.compute_coll(ball2, step)
  ```

  Assuming that you don't have any more expensive checks for comparing
  balls, `ball1 is not ball2` should be just a pointer comparison, so
  reasonably fast.  Edit: I update this from the comment; of course
  `is not` is better than `!=` for the reason I mentioned already.

For the NumPy things I can just recommend looking at already predefined
functions in NumPy/SciPy that are hopefully implemented in C(ython), not
recalculating values, i.e. just store every reusable value if possible,
possibly looking at other ways of representing your data (matrixes to
use fast matrix/matrix operations?) and finally using Cython to run
maths directly in C if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really makes my code simpler :) but it doesn't really improve perf when I check execution time. Maybe I should take a look to Cython, I thought about using fortran and f2py too.

Comment: About `ball1 != ball2`, I noticed that `ball1 is not ball2` is significantly faster. Execution takes 15s instead of 17s.

Comment: My bad, yes, that would be even better.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that can be improved here.

1. In Python, using a `_` before a class variable denotes a protected member of the class, I don't think that was your intention so you can just make it the following without the preceding `_`'s in `__init__` like this, and throughout the program.

   ```
   self.mass = mass
   self.radius = radius
   self.position = position
   self.velocity = velocity
   self.vafter = np.copy(velocity) # temp storage for velocity of next step
   ```
2. Your `compute_coil` method is mostly just naming variables.

   Since we have alot of lines like this,

   ```
   m1 = self.mass
   m2 = ball.mass
   ```

   we can re-write them on one line like this,

   ```
   m1, m2 = self.mass, ball.mass
   ```

   That would change the first part of your `compute_coll` method to,

   ```
   m1, m2 = self.mass, ball.mass
   r1, r2 = self.radius, ball.radius
   v1, v2 = self.velocity, ball.velocity
   x1, x2 = self.position, ball.position
   di = x2-x1
   ```

   which I feel reduces a lot of unnecessary clutter.
3. In your `compute_coll` method you have a little more tidying that can be done.

   According to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/),

   ```
   v1-v2,di
   ```

   should be,

   ```
   v1-v2, di
   ```

   with whitespace after the `,`. *You also do this in a few of your other methods*.
4. You miss some more whitespace in your `step1` function around the `!=` operator.

   ```
   if i!=j:
   ```

   should be,

   ```
   if i != j:
   ```
5. In your function `init_list(N)`, your argument `N` is uppercase. According to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) argument names should be lowercase.