# Display a simulation using Tkinter

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, gui, tkinter

I wrote a module to simulate physics of 2D elastic balls and the community helped me to improve it [on this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125867/simulation-of-2d-elastic-balls).

Now I implemented a GUI using Tkinter to display the simulation in a window.

I'm a beginner in programming GUI and I don't know if my script can be more efficient and/or simpler.

Indeed, I'm not really satisfied by my `display` function because it includes definitions of other functions dedicated to the buttons commands.

Moreover, when I push the start button twice, I also need to push the pause button twice to stop the simulation. I don't understand this behaviour !

**Import modules**

```
import Tkinter as tk
import solver
```

You'll find the solver module [here](https://github.com/cromod/Collision/blob/master/solver.py). This isn't the object of this post. If you've comments or remarks about it, post them on this post I spoke above.

**Surrounding functions**

```
def _create_circle(self, x, y, r, **kwargs):
    """Create a circle

    x the abscissa of centre
    y the ordinate of centre
    r the radius of circle
    **kwargs optional arguments
    return the drawing of a circle
    """
    return self.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, **kwargs)
tk.Canvas.create_circle = _create_circle

def _coords_circle(self, target, x, y, r, **kwargs):
    """Define a circle

    target the circle object
    x the abscissa of centre
    y the ordinate of centre
    r the radius of circle
    **kwargs optional arguments
    return the circle drawing with updated coordinates
    """
    return self.coords(target, x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, **kwargs)
tk.Canvas.coords_circle = _coords_circle

def create(balls, canvas):
    """Create a drawing item for each solver.Ball object

    balls the list of solver.Ball objects
    canvas the Tkinter.Canvas oject
    return a dictionary with solver.Ball objects as keys and their circle drawings as items
    """
    return {ball: canvas.create_circle(ball.position[0], ball.position[1], ball.radius, fill="white") for ball in balls}

def update(drawing, canvas, step, size):
    """Update the drawing items for a time step

    drawing the dictionary of drawing items
    canvas the Tkinter.Canvas oject
    step the time step
    size the medium size
    """
    balls = drawing.keys()
    solver.solve_step(balls, step, size)
    for ball in balls:
        canvas.coords_circle(drawing[ball], ball.position[0], ball.position[1], ball.radius)
    canvas.update()
```

**`display` function**

```
def display(balls, step, size):
    """Display the simulation

    balls the list of solver.Ball objects
    step the time step
    size the medium size
    """
    # Instanciate the window, canvas and circle objects
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.poll = True
    canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=size, height=size, bg="black")
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.focus_set()
    drawing = create(balls, canvas)
    # Define functions to launch and stop the simulation
    def animate():
        """Animate the drawing items"""
        if window.poll:
            update(drawing, canvas, step, size)
            window.after(0, animate)
        else:
            window.poll = True
    def stop():
        """Stop the animation"""
        window.poll = False
    # Define the buttons used to launch and stop the simulation
    start_button = tk.Button(window, text="Start", command=animate)
    stop_button = tk.Button(window, text="Pause", command=stop)
    start_button.pack()
    stop_button.pack()
    # GUI loop
    window.mainloop()
```

**Unit test of `display` function**

```
# Test this module
if __name__ == "__main__":
    balls = [solver.Ball(20., 20., [40.,40.], [5.,5.]), solver.Ball(10., 10., [480.,480.], [-15.,-15.]), solver.Ball(15., 15., [30.,470.], [10.,-10.])]
    size = 500.
    step = 0.1
    display(balls, step, size)
```

Comment: Is this python 2.7 or 3?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 but I think it works with python 3 if you replace `import Tkinter as tk` by `import tkinter as tk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I didn't get any answer, I propose the following improvements.

First I didn't change the functions `create_circle` and `coords_circle`.

I found a more satisfying solution for the `display` function. Indeed, I create a class `Display` and implement the former `display` function in its `__init__` method.

```
class Display:
    """Define the window used to display a simulation"""

    def __init__(self, balls, step, size):
        """Initialize and launch the display"""
        self.balls = balls
        self.step = step
        self.size = size

        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.window, width=self.size, height=self.size, bg="black")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.focus_set()
        self.drawing = self.create()
        self.started = False

        start_button = tk.Button(self.window, text="Start", command=self.start)
        stop_button = tk.Button(self.window, text="Pause", command=self.stop)
        start_button.pack()
        stop_button.pack()

        self.window.mainloop()
```

In this way, I can define the `animate` and `stop` functions as methods of the class `Display` rather than inside `__init__`.

The objects `balls`, `step`, `size`, `window`, `canvas`, `drawing`, `start_button` and `stop_button` become attributes of the class Display. So I don't need to put them in arguments of `create` and `update` methods.

```
def create(self):
    """Create a drawing item for each solver.Ball object

    return a dictionary with solver.Ball objects as keys and their circle drawings as items
    """
    return {ball: self.canvas.create_circle(ball.position[0], ball.position[1], ball.radius, fill="white") for ball in self.balls}

def update(self):
    """Update the drawing items for a time step"""
    solver.solve_step(self.balls, self.step, self.size)
    for ball in self.balls:
        self.canvas.coords_circle(self.drawing[ball], ball.position[0], ball.position[1], ball.radius)
    self.canvas.update()
```

Moreover, the start button calls the `start` method that calls the `animate` method only if the value of `started` is `False`. Thus, we don't have the bad behaviour raised in the question (need to push the pause button twice after pushing the start button twice).

```
def start(self):
    """Start the animation"""
    if not self.started:
        self.started = True
        self.animate()

def animate(self):
    """Animate the drawing items"""
    if self.started:
        self.update()
        self.window.after(0, self.animate)

def stop(self):
    """Stop the animation"""
    self.started = False
```

You'll find the complete code [here](https://github.com/cromod/Collision/blob/master/display.py).